# This is a plugin code that supposed to add badge/label Infront of post title but i don't understand why it is showing the code tags in frontend

Tags: plugins, posts

I want it to display the label/badge infront of title not inside the title because it keep showing the code tags.

```
/* added farbtastic script and css while adding badges from backend */
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts','tmpl_badge_admin_head_script',99);
function tmpl_badge_admin_head_script(){
    wp_enqueue_script('farbtastic');
    wp_enqueue_style('farbtastic');   
}


register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'tmpl_badge_activate');
/* while activation save variable to show activation message  */
function tmpl_badge_activate() {
    add_option('tmpl_badge_activate_msg', 'y');
}

/* This function display admin notice to activate templatic-badge plugin, if they first activated */
add_action('admin_notices','tmpl_badge_admin_notices',99);

function tmpl_badge_admin_notices(){
    if (get_option('tmpl_badge_activate_msg') == 'y') {
        echo '<div class="updated"><p>'.  __('Templatic - Badges plugin is activated successfully. Badges can be added from Add Post page in backend from "Templatic Badge" section.','templatic_badge') . '</p></div>';
        delete_option('tmpl_badge_activate_msg');
    }
}

/* Class for templatic badges where badges are saved and shown besides title */
class templaticBadges 
{
    /* call default construtor */
    function __construct() 
    {
        
        /* action to show metabox at backend */
        add_action('admin_init',array($this,'tmpl_badge_meta_box'));

        /* save badge in post meta table */
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'tmpl_badge_save_post' ), 1, 2 );

    }
    
    /* call badge metabox  */
    function tmpl_badge_meta_box(){

        global $post;
        
        /* names or objects */
        $output = 'objects'; 
        $args = array();

        /* names or objects, note names is the default */
        $output = 'names'; 
        
        /* 'and' or 'or' */
        $operator = 'and'; 

        $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 
    $exclude_post_type = apply_filters('tmpl_badge_unset_post_type',array('page','attachment','revision','nav_menu_item'));
    
    
    /* loop for post type to show post detail template */
    foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {

        if(in_array($post_type,$exclude_post_type))
            continue;
       
       /*show single page template for custom post type*/
        add_meta_box( 'templatic_badge', __( 'Templatic Badge', 'templatic_badge' ), array( $this,'tmpl_badge_meta_box_content'), $post_type, 'side','high',$post );
    }
    
}


/* display metabox for each post type */
function tmpl_badge_meta_box_content(){
    global $post;
    $newbadge_title=get_post_meta($post->ID,'newbadge_title',true);
    $newbadge_color=get_post_meta($post->ID,'newbadge_color',true);
    $newbadge_color=($newbadge_color!='')?$newbadge_color:'#';
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="tmpl_noncename" id="tmpl_noncename" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ); ?>" />
    <ul class="badge_list">
        <li>
            <label><strong><?php echo _e('Badge Title','templatic_badge');?></strong></label><span><input type="text" name="newbadge_title" value="<?php echo $newbadge_title?>" /></span>
            <p class="description"><?php _e('This title will appear as a badge on your listings, detail pages and widgets.','templatic_badge');?></p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label><strong><?php echo _e('Color','templatic_badge');?></strong></label>
            <span><input type="text" name="newbadge_color" value="<?php echo $newbadge_color;?>"  id="newbadge_color_picker" /></span>
            <a id="close_newbadge_color_picker" style="display:none"><span class="dashicons dashicons-dismiss"></span></a>
            <div class="farbtastic_color" id="color_newbadge_color_picker"  name="newbadge_color_picker" style="display:none" >
            </div>
            <p class="description"><?php _e('Select color for your new badge.','templatic_badge');?></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery("#color_newbadge_color_picker").farbtastic("#newbadge_color_picker");
        jQuery(document).on( 'click focus','#newbadge_color_picker', function(e) {
            jQuery('[name="newbadge_color_picker"]').css('display', 'block');
            jQuery('#close_newbadge_color_picker').css('display', 'block');
            return false;
        });
        jQuery(document).on( 'click focus','#close_newbadge_color_picker', function(e) {
            jQuery('[name="newbadge_color_picker"]').css('display', 'none');
            jQuery('#close_newbadge_color_picker').css('display', 'none');
            return false;
        });
        
    }); 
    </script>
    <?php
}


/*   Save Directory NewBadge filed save  */

function tmpl_badge_save_post($post_id,$post){
    
    /*
     * Verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because save_post can be triggered at other times
     */
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['tmpl_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return $post->ID;

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {      
        return ;    
    }
    
    /* names or objects */
    $output = 'objects'; 
    $args = array();

    /* names or objects, note names is the default */
    $output = 'names'; 
    
    /* 'and' or 'or' */
    $operator = 'and'; 

    $post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 
    
    if(!empty($post_types) && in_array($_POST['post_type'],$post_types)){       
        update_post_meta($post_id,'newbadge_title',$_POST['newbadge_title']);
        update_post_meta($post_id,'newbadge_color',$_POST['newbadge_color']);
    }
}

} /* end class */


add_filter('the_title','tmpl_badge_tag',10,2);
/* to show badge beside post title where we have used wordpress the_title   */
function tmpl_badge_tag($title,$post_id){
    global $post;
    if(!is_admin())
    {
        $newbadge_title=get_post_meta($post_id,'newbadge_title',true);
        $newbadge_title=($newbadge_title!="")? $newbadge_title : '';
        $newbadge_color=get_post_meta($post_id,'newbadge_color',true);  
        $tmpl_display_badge = '';
        
        if($newbadge_title!=''){        
            
            $tmpl_display_badge = '<span class="badge-status" style="background:'. $newbadge_color.'">'. $newbadge_title.'</span>&nbsp;';
            
        }
        
        return apply_filters('tmpl_title_badge',$title.$tmpl_display_badge);
    }
    else
        return $title;
}

$templ = new templaticBadges(); // go

/* include css in for badge */
add_action('wp_head','tmpl_badge_wp_footer');
function tmpl_badge_wp_footer(){
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .badge-status { display:inline; font-size:11px; color:#fff; padding:3px 5px; margin:5px;  position: relative; top:-7px;
            -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;}
        .widget .badge-status {top:-3px; font-size:10px; }
    </style>
    <?php   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing could be due to the location where you're adding the badge in your code. The badge is appended to the post title, hence it might be appearing within the title element, which could be causing the code tags to appear.

Here an example code, based from your current code, where the badge is prepended to the post title. This way, it will appear in front of the post title instead of within it.

```
add_filter('the_title','tmpl_badge_tag',10,2); 

function tmpl_badge_tag($title,$post_id){ 
    global $post; 

    if(!is_admin()) { 
        $newbadge_title=get_post_meta($post_id,'newbadge_title',true); 
        $newbadge_title=($newbadge_title!="")? $newbadge_title : ''; 
        $newbadge_color=get_post_meta($post_id,'newbadge_color',true);
        $tmpl_display_badge = '';

        if($newbadge_title!=''){        
            $tmpl_display_badge = '<span class="badge-status" style="background:'. $newbadge_color.'">'. $newbadge_title.'</span>&nbsp;';
        }

        // prepend the badge to the title
        return apply_filters('tmpl_title_badge', $tmpl_display_badge . $title);
    }
    else
        return $title;
}

$templ = new templaticBadges();

add_action('wp_head','tmpl_badge_wp_footer'); 

function tmpl_badge_wp_footer(){ 
    ?> 
    .badge-status { 
        display:inline; 
        font-size:11px; 
        color:#fff; 
        padding:3px 5px; 
        margin:5px; 
        position: relative; 
        top:-7px; 
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px; 
        -moz-border-radius: 3px; 
        border-radius: 3px;
    } 

    .widget .badge-status {
        top:-3px; 
        font-size:10px; 
    } 
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately still didn't work. I just updated my question with the full plugin code, kindly look into it. The plugin is supposed to add it to specific post i set it for, and not all the posts. Also not within the post title but after it. It supposed to show as a label/badge.